# Tab filtering with angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I am taking a long overdue Angular workshop and I am trying to convert a page from regular JQuery to Angular functionality. One of the things I am stuck on is activating a filter with ng-click (at least I think that is the preferred method).

So basically I have a gallery and a menu on the left with the categories(groups) of these images in the gallery. The groups show according to the menu on the left. So, 4 groups (Girls, Nature, Music, Space). The images are divided into these groups. If I press on girls, I should see only the images in the group:girls, if I press nature, I should see only the pictures in group:nature and so on, If I press All, I should see them all.

Well, it's not working. Even though I followed this [How to filter a list in AngularJS using several links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379934/how-to-filter-a-list-in-angularjs-using-several-links).

Here is a visual of the page to give an idea

And here is my code

**HTML**

```
<div class="content-body" ng-controller="galleryController as panel">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
    <div class="content-sidebar">
      <div class="side-widget menu">
        <h4>Groups:</h4>
        <div class="border-bottom">
          <ul ng-init="tab = 1" class="list-group">
            <li ng-class="{active:panel.isSelected(1)}">
              <a class="list-group-item" ng-click="panel.selectTab(1); groupFilter = {}">All <span
                                            class="badge badge-primary">12</span></a>
            </li>
            <li ng-class="{active:panel.isSelected(2)}">
              <a class="list-group-item" ng-click="panel.selectTab(2); groupFilter ={group:'nature'}">Nature <span
                                                class="badge badge-success">7</span></a>
            </li>
            <li ng-class="{active:panel.isSelected(3)}">
              <a class="list-group-item" ng-click="panel.selectTab(3)">Music <span
                                                class="badge badge-danger">3</span></a>
            </li>
            <li ng-class="{active:panel.isSelected(4)}">
              <a class="list-group-item" ng-click="panel.selectTab(4)">Space <span
                                                class="badge badge-info">2</span></a>
            </li>
            <li ng-class="{active:panel.isSelected(5)}">
              <a class="list-group-item" ng-click="panel.selectTab(5)">Girls <span
                                                class="badge badge-warning">3</span></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9">
    <div class="gallery">
      <div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3" ng-repeat="gallery in galleries | filter:groupFilter">
            <a class="gallery-item" ng-href="{{gallery.img}}" ng-class="{true:'active',false:''}[checked]"
               title="Nature Image 1" >
                <div class="image">
                    <img ng-src="{{gallery.img}}" alt="Nature Image 1"/>

                </div>
                <div class="meta">
                    <strong>{{gallery.title}}</strong>
                    <span>{{gallery.desc}}</span>
                </div>
            </a>
            <ul class="gallery-item-controls">
                <li><label class="check"><input type="checkbox" class="icheckbox" ng-model="checked" /></label></li>
                <li><span class="gallery-item-remove"><i class="fa fa-times" ng-click="removeGalleryItem(galleryItem, $event)"></i></span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The **Controller** if you need to see it

```
app.controller('galleryController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('data/galleries.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.galleries = data;
    });

    $scope.removeGalleryItem=function(gallery){
        var removedGallery = $scope.galleries.indexOf(gallery);
        $scope.galleries.splice(removedGallery, 1);
    };

    this.tab = 1;

    this.selectTab = function(setTab){
        this.tab = setTab;
    };

    this.isSelected = function(checkTab){
        return this.tab === checkTab;
    };



}]);
```

The **Data**

```
[
{
  "img":"assets/images/gallery/girls-1.jpg",
  "group": "girls",
  "title": "Image 1",
  "desc": "Description",
  "link":""
},
{
  "img":"assets/images/gallery/girls-2.jpg",
  "group": "girls",
  "title": "Image 2",
  "desc": "Description",
  "link":""
},
{
  "img":"assets/images/gallery/girls-3.jpg",
  "group": "girls",
  "title": "Image 3",
  "desc": "Description",
  "link":""
},
{
  "img":"assets/images/gallery/music-1.jpg",
  "group": "music",
  "title": "Image 4",
  "desc": "Description",
  "link":""
},
{
  "img":"assets/images/gallery/music-2.jpg",
  "group": "music",
  "title": "Image 5",
  "desc": "Description",
  "link":""
},
{
  "img":"assets/images/gallery/music-3.jpg",
  "group": "music",
  "title": "Image 6",
  "desc": "Description",
  "link":""
},
{
  "img":"assets/images/gallery/music-4.jpg",
  "group": "music",
  "title": "Image 7",
  "desc": "Description",
  "link":""
},
{
  "img":"assets/images/gallery/music-5.jpg",
  "group": "music",
  "title": "Image 8",
  "desc": "Description",
  "link":""
},
{
  "img":"assets/images/gallery/nature-1.jpg",
  "group": "nature",
  "title": "Image 9",
  "desc": "Description",
  "link":""
},
{
  "img":"assets/images/gallery/nature-2.jpg",
  "group": "nature",
  "title": "Image 10",
  "desc": "Description",
  "link":""
},
{
  "img":"assets/images/gallery/nature-3.jpg",
  "group": "nature",
  "title": "Image 11",
  "desc": "Description",
  "link":""
},
{
  "img":"assets/images/gallery/nature-4.jpg",
  "group": "nature",
  "title": "Image 12",
  "desc": "Description",
  "link":""
},
{
  "img":"assets/images/gallery/nature-5.jpg",
  "group": "nature",
  "title": "Image 13",
  "desc": "Description",
  "link":""
},
{
  "img":"assets/images/gallery/nature-6.jpg",
  "group": "nature",
  "title": "Image 14",
  "desc": "Description",
  "link":""
},
{
  "img":"assets/images/gallery/nature-7.jpg",
  "group": "nature",
  "title": "Image 15",
  "desc": "Description",
  "link":""
},
{
  "img":"assets/images/gallery/space-1.jpg",
  "group": "space",
  "title": "Image 16",
  "desc": "Description",
  "link":""
},
{
  "img":"assets/images/gallery/space-2.jpg",
  "group": "space",
  "title": "Image 17",
  "desc": "Description",
  "link":""
}
]
```

Just in case you're wondering what is in the controller. A remove gallery item that is not workig either, but that's for another question. And a couple of functions to add the active class to the menu so that it shows when it is active.

According to the tutorial above, there is nothing needed in the controller to make the filtering work because it is all included in Angular out of the box.

**EDIT**
Any ideas how to make this filetering work with the data separated from the app.js file.

Here's a [**link**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/eBzNOr?editors=1010) for a codepen. As you can see it works if I put the data in the apps file but not when I remote to it (as it should be) Do I need to build a factory? Comment out the data in the app.js and leave the remote to a repo that contains the json and images and see it fail

[image]

Comment: Just tried your code here : https://jsfiddle.net/kqrpz2mq/ Works like a charm with group = nature, the only one you have implemented

Comment: It does make me happy to see there's nothing wrong ultimately with the filtering in essence, but it still doesn't work as intended. I added a codepen that shows it working when the data is added in the app.js file but it fails when I connect to my data externally. I need the data to be separated. Eventually this data will be maintained as a database

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the request of the OP I am adding an answer here that is similar to one that I wrote for another of their questions.

**Note to OP** - maybe edit it so future readers aren't confused :-)

---

After doing some research I think the problem is that **galleryController** is defined somewhere in your markup but the elements in the gallery are not inside of where that controller is defined.

Referring to http://joli.sitedev.online/#/gallery. In file slidesController.js where galleryController is defined I put a break here and the code pauses:

[image]

I also put a break point here but the code does not pause when clicking on a delete button:

[image]

Looking at the markup I can't see any sign of `ng-controller="galleryController"` so I can't see how **galleries** in the `ng-repeat` is populated:

[image]

Maybe it is through this:

[image]

If it is through that then it would explain things as that directive has its own controller. Any further information would help and I'm sure we can clear this up.

Comment: Point taken. Your answer to the other question applies to this one but they're not one in the same. However, those who may come here will have find this answer helpful to this problem. Thanks again bud!

Answer (score 1):

**That is because of cross orign**

Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that allows restricted resources (e.g. fonts) on a web page to be requested from another domain outside the domain from which the resource originated.[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) A web page may freely embed images, stylesheets, scripts, iframes, videos.[2] Certain "cross-domain" requests, notably AJAX requests, however are forbidden by default by the same-origin security policy.

If you Inspet your browser you can see the error of [cross orign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)